# TypeError: this.comp.setContainerTransform is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

While migrating AG grid code I got following error

```
TypeError: this.comp.setContainerTransform is not a function
    at HeaderRowContainerCtrl.setHorizontalScroll (http://localhost:3001/static/js/vendors-node_modules_ag-grid-react_main_js-node_modules_ag-grid-community_styles_ag-grid_css--0fb06a.chunk.js:34421:15)
    at GridBodyScrollFeature.horizontallyScrollHeaderCenterAndFloatingCenter (http://localhost:3001/static/js/vendors-node_modules_ag-grid-react_main_js-node_modules_ag-grid-community_styles_ag-grid_css--0fb06a.chunk.js:22452:27)
    at GridBodyScrollFeature.doHorizontalScroll (http://localhost:3001/static/js/vendors-node_modules_ag-grid-react_main_js-node_modules_ag-grid-community_styles_ag-grid_css--0fb06a.chunk.js:22548:10)
    at GridBodyScrollFeature.onHScrollCommon (http://localhost:3001/static/js/vendors-node_modules_ag-grid-react_main_js-node_modules_ag-grid-community_styles_ag-grid_css--0fb06a.chunk.js:22501:10)
    at GridBodyScrollFeature.checkScrollLeft (http://localhost:3001/static/js/vendors-node_modules_ag-grid-react_main_js-node_modules_ag-grid-community_styles_ag-grid_css--0fb06a.chunk.js:22622:12)
    at ViewportSizeFeature.checkViewportAndScrolls (http://localhost:3001/static/js/vendors-node_modules_ag-grid-react_main_js-node_modules_ag-grid-community_styles_ag-grid_css--0fb06a.chunk.js:27890:42)
    at ViewportSizeFeature.onCenterViewportResized (http://localhost:3001/static/js/vendors-node_modules_ag-grid-react_main_js-node_modules_ag-grid-community_styles_ag-grid_css--0fb06a.chunk.js:27867:12)
    at ResizeObserver.listener (http://localhost:3001/static/js/vendors-node_modules_ag-grid-react_main_js-node_modules_ag-grid-community_styles_ag-grid_css--0fb06a.chunk.js:27855:20)
    at http://localhost:3001/static/js/vendors-node_modules_ag-grid-react_main_js-node_modules_ag-grid-community_styles_ag-grid_css--0fb06a.chunk.js:756:12
```

I am getting the following error while migrating the project. The previously ag-grid-react version was `24.1.0` now the current project has `ag-grid-react` version `29.1.0` which might be the issue.

Previous Version

```
"@ag-grid-enterprise/core": "^24.1.0",
"ag-grid-community": "^24.1.0",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "^24.1.0",
"ag-grid-react": "^24.1.1",
```

Current Version

```
  "ag-grid-community": "^29.1.0",
  "ag-grid-enterprise": "^29.1.0",
  "ag-grid-react": "^29.1.0",
```